# Music stops/pauses when the screen locks

Tags: greeter, music, audio

Whenever I play music in Noise, it pauses when the screen locks? Any solution?

Comment: Actually it is not a bug but a design decision.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and found a workaround while going through the comment on the bug reports:

Add your user account to the `audio` group by running `sudo adduser user audio` with user being your user account name.

Comment: I logged in and out a few times only to realize I needed to reboot, then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

It's not just Noise (the music app) but YouTube videos, Spotify, and all system audio stops/pauses when the screen locks (or machine suspends).

The easiest solution is to change the settings for when the screen turns off (turns to lock screen), which is set for 15 minutes by default in `Settings > Power`. I agree that system audio should continue in the background when the screen is locked (it's not like the computer suspends). [Subscribe to the feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1451210) to track its progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a terminal and type (be aware of update user with your username before executing the command):

```
sudo adduser user audio
```

Reboot your system and done!

Answer (score 0):

Works fine - but only for the current song. An music player (music, audacious) stops after the current song finished. Once the lock is removed, these apps continue playing further songs. Any further help (except not using a screen locker)?
Before I ran eOS 5.1 Hera and I can't remember having this problems.